# Error when sending an email with an attached file

Tags: java, android, mobile-development

My application requires the function of sending attached files from external storage by email using third-party applications like GMail. However, when I try to do this, an exception is thrown that does not clarify the situation.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    File simpleFile;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        simpleFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "simple_file.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos = null;

        try {
            if (!simpleFile.exists()) {
                simpleFile.createNewFile();
            }

            fos = new FileOutputStream(simpleFile);
            fos.write("Some simple text".getBytes());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void sendEmail(View view) {
        // triggered when the button is clicked
        Intent emailIntent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
     
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"xxxxxxx@gmail.com"});
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Some subject");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some text");

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(simpleFile);
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email"));
    }
}
```

The error occurs when startActivity() is triggered in the last line.Help me please figure out where the problem lies.

Stacktrace:

````
    Process: com.example.checksendemail, PID: 13328
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
     Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.checksendemail/files/simple_file.txt exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()
        at android.os.StrictMode.onFileUriExposed(StrictMode.java:1958)
        at android.net.Uri.checkFileUriExposed(Uri.java:2356)
        at android.content.ClipData.prepareToLeaveProcess(ClipData.java:941)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9735)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9741)
        at android.content.Intent.prepareToLeaveProcess(Intent.java:9720)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1609)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4430)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4791)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4759)
        at com.example.checksendemail.MainActivity.sendEmail(MainActivity.java:59)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256) 
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) ```
````

Comment: Maybe the exception does not clarify the situation to you but maybe it would tell us all.

Comment: @blackapps  I added stacktrace in question

Comment: `FileUriExposedException`

Comment: @blackapps It is clear that the error is here. But the file exists in the file system.

Comment: Yes. That will be so. But that is not the message you got. It is not about a file that not exists but about an uri that is exposed.

Comment: @blackapps well, thank you! Please tell me how to fix this error.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: @blackapps I was looking for a solution to this problem on the internet. But all the examples are from there for earlier versions of the api. They don't work anymore. That's why I published a post on stackoverflow

Comment: The solution for a FileUriExposedException is still the same since Android N. One small google will give you so many stackoverflow pages where your problem is reported and solved.